# rails 4 form_for with f.select isn't passing correct params, getting `param is missing` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, form-for

I have a shared partial using `select` fields and `options_for_select` that isn't passing the correct params to the controller.

In the users_controller.rb, the view page user_home.html.erb:

```
def user_home
  if user_signed_in?
    @user = current_user
    @cpe_event = CpeEvent.new
  end
end
```

In my cpe_events_controller.rb I have a #create action:

```
def create
  @cpe_event = CpeEvent.new
  @user = current_user     
  @cpe_event = current_user.cpe_events.build(cpe_event_params)
  ...
```

The data is submitted by a form_for - a shared partial (rendered by a users_controller view) - with a dropdown of several sponsors to select from.  And which, I should add, is one of three dropdowns that are chained using jQuery:

```
<%= form_for @cpe_event, url: cpe_events_path, method: :post, 
  html: { multipart: true }, class: 'form-inline form_for form_for_content' do |f| %>
<div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="float: left;">
    <% f.label :sponsor_name %>
    <%= f.select :sponsor_name, options_for_select(@sponsor_names), {},
      { class: "sponsor_name form-control btn-default", name: "sponsor_name"} %>
</div> 
....
```

I suspect the issue is `f.select` rather than `f.text-field` - and how one properly submits that data using a form_for.

I am getting this error on the `@cpe_event = current_user.cpe_events.build(cpe_event_params)` line of the `cpe_events_controller.rb`:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: cpe_event
```

The permitted params code is:

```
def cpe_event_params
  params.require(:cpe_event).permit(....
```

If I place `raise params.inspect` after `def create`, I get a hash of the params submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u1...1g==", "sponsor_name"=>"WI - TEST",
"class_date"=>"2014-01-01", "title"=>"How Account", "commit"=>"Submit",
"controller"=>"cpe_events", "action"=>"create"}
```

Which is why I'm getting a 400 error, i.e., it doesn't contain

```
`"cpe_event" => {"sponsor_name"=>"WI - TEST", "class_date"=>"2014-01-01",
 "title"=>"How Account"...`
```

I've tried submitted the form with a symbol `:cpe_event` rather than a model object `@cpe_event` with no luck.

How do I correct the code in order to submit the correct / properly formatted params? Thanks!

Comment: If you view source on the `new` page, and look at the `name` attribute of the inputs, are they `cpe_event[sonsor_name]` or just `sponsor_name`?

Comment: Oh, you set `name: "sponsor_name"` in your html options. Either change that to `name: "cpe_event[sponsor_name]"` or just remove it. Then do the same with `class_date`, `title`, etc.

Comment: Clark - Thank you for responding.  Here's the 'view source':

Comment: Opps, didn't save quick enough: `<select class="sponsor_name form-control btn-default" name="sponsor_name" id="cpe_event_sponsor_name"><option value="Sponsor (select)">Sponsor (select)</option>
<option value="WI - TEST">WI - TEST</option>`
<option value="IL - TEST">IL - TEST</option>
<option value="IN - TEST">IN - TEST</option></select>
    </div>

Comment: Right, so it's the name. The default thing ruby will do in your `form_for <object> do |f|` is hash all fields to the object name if you relate them with `f.<input type>` It does that by setting the name to `<object_name>[<attribute_name>]` So when you changed the name, `name: "sponsor_name"` you removed it from the hash.

Comment: `name: "cpe_event[sponsor_name]" shows the correct params in the server logs `Parameters: {"cpe_event"=>{"sponsor_name"=>"WI - TEST", "class_date"=>""}}`  However, in the console, I get a 500 internal server error because the jQuery chaining breaks.  I'm using the jQuery Chained Select Plugin `http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained`

Comment: You may be better configuring that plugin to work with the rails names, rather than trying to convert the parameters after.

Comment: I will add some options on how you may do it by changing the params though, I can't help with the plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question relates to the use of a ruby on rails / rails form (`form_for`) with `select` and `options_for_select` that throws a `param is missing error` when submitted.  The selections are chained using the  [jQuery Chained Selects Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)  The chaining end-point causes the params error which Clark resolved with these work-arounds:

Here are 2 different options if you want to keep your HTML, and plugin setup as is.

In JQuery - As I say in the comment below, you should add a class to to the specific inputs for cpe_event, ex `cpe_event_param` and use `$('.cpe_event_param')` instead of `$('input')`

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('input').each(function() { //should probably use a class for this so you only do it to specific inputs
        $(this).attr('name', 'cpe_event[' + $(this).attr('name') + ']');
    });
});
```

or in rails -

```
def cpe_event_params
  cpe_event = Hash.new
  params.each do |k,v|
    cpe_event[k] = v
  end
  params[:cpe_event] = cpe_event
  #everything else you had
```

Comment: Clark - Thank you! I edited your answer to include more information - so that others will find it when searching.  If the edits are OK I'll accept your answer.  Best, Doug

Comment: A msg says that it's only visible to me until reviewed, so here's my addition: The question relates to the use of a ruby on rails / rails form (form_for) with select and options_for_select that throws a param is missing error when submitted. The selections are chained using the jQuery Chained Selects Plugin The chaining end-point causes the params error which Clark resolved with these work-arounds:

Comment: @user3763682 I was able to read the suggested edit, I guess it should say it is only visible to you, and anyone who can review it. I'm glad you were able to isolate the problem and that my suggestions worked for you. I have approved the edit.